# CSS: Remove Password Text Input green underline - Chrome Autofill

Tags: css, google-chrome, authentication, frontend, autofill

[image]

How can I remove the Bright green underline that is added to the login form `password` field, which I think chrome is adding. My current design in using `materializecss` and though minor it looks odd and changes the aesthetics of the form. I already made chrome Autofill boxes transparent using below code.

```
@-webkit-keyframes autofill {

    0%,
    100% {
        color: #666;
        background: transparent;
    }
}

input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    /* Safari support - any positive time runs instantly */
    -webkit-animation-name: autofill;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

`Materialize` adds `teal` underline as per it's design theme. I want to retain that.

Answer (score 0):

I was assuming wrong, `Chrome` is not the culprit. The underline is added by the `materializecss`

```
      <input type="password" name="password" class="validate">
```

`Validate` class which I had enabled on the password field, shows bright green for valid and red for invalid. Personally I think by it's against default `Teal` underline design. Removed the same.

```
      <input type="password" name="password">
```